# PHP+SQL Shuffle results from one table and save to onother one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, shuffle

I have to write script in PHP which shuffle players IDs, pair them and save to another one table.

From the first table I get player IDs using simple SQL query:

```
SELECT id FROM table1
```

It gives me e.g. result with IDs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Now my issue begins.

I have to shuffle SQL result to get e.g. result 2, 5, 4, 1, 3

Then I need to pair players IDs (after shuffle) like that:

```
first row - first player with second player
second row - second player with third player
third row - third player with fourth player
fourth row - fourth player with fifth player
fifth row - fifth player with first player
```

In SQL table2 if should look like below:

```
2-5
5-4
4-1
1-3
3-2
```

What I am looking for is:
1. Way to shuffle sql result with players ID
2. Way to pair results from shuffled result
3. Way to save it to table2

Comment: What have tried so far? For step 1 you can use `RAND()` in your query - `SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY RAND()`. For step 2 & 3 show your code attempts.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use shffle().  What it does is it takes your array and shuffles it.  then you can just use each array in order.

example

```
array1
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]

array2
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]

 $array3 = shuffle($array2);

array3 
[2]
[1]
[4]
[3]
```

then loop through them

```
for($i=0;$i<4;i++){
    echo $array1[$i] .' vs '. $array3[$i];
}
```

Comment: Using this method you would occasionally get 1v1 or  2v2 or etc

Comment: you would need to do $array3 = shuffle($array2);  I just fixed the code.  Refresh.

Comment: Also here is the documentation for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I found out:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1");

$numbers=array();

    while ($result_data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
      array_push($numbers, $result_data[0]);
    }

shuffle($numbers);
$numbers2 = $numbers;
array_unshift( $numbers2, array_pop( $numbers2 ) );


for($i=0;$i<count($numbers);$i++){
    echo $numbers2[$i].' vs '.$numbers[$i] . '<br />';
}
```